# How do I make a stylized procedural tree texture?

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to recreate this tree texture from genshin impact with procedural nodes:
[image]

This is what I have and it looks nothing like it:

[image]

Any ideas how I can get it a little more similar? Or some resources I could look for? Thanks!

This is the blender file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F8Jw_H1wxgR6rdGN9AtDGxXbL-F2Wa6k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That looks like it has custom high poly detail sculpted and baked down.

Comment: Or maybe a baked cavity map from a high-poly sculpt. But this is also not procedural and requires baked textures.

Comment: Dang it, I knew it'd be too easy otherwise lol, thank you both.